# Will AWS DAX of Dynamodb cache null result when GetItem result is null?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I have a question about null result caching behavior of Amazon DAX. If I try to `GetItem` from DAX with Dynamodb, and the item result is null. Will the DAX cache the null result to accelerate the get null item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. DAX caches null marker if item is not found in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DAX will cache the negative result:

> DAX supports negative cache entries, in both the item cache and the
>   query cache. A negative cache entry occurs when DAX cannot find
>   requested items in an underlying DynamoDB table. Instead of generating
>   an error, DAX caches an empty result and returns that result to the
>   user.
>
> A negative cache entry will remain in the DAX item cache until its
>   item TTL has expired, LRU is invoked, or until the item is modified
>   using PutItem, UpdateItem or DeleteItem.

From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.consistency.html#DAX.consistency.negative-caching